# Oops! Something Bad Happened! Newsletter preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, newsletter

I was on https://stackexchange.com/newsletters and tried to preview the Android Enthusiasts newsletter, and the pop-up contained the **Oops! Something Bad Happened!** page.

I tried for StackOverflow, of which I'm a member, and it worked fine (I had already previewed that newsletter from StackOverflow itself) but then I tried English Language and Usage, of which I'm also a member, and it did *not* work. I then went directly to the English page, and tried there, but it still crashed.

Finally, I tried it logged out, and in both Firefox and Chrome, and in all cases StackOverflow preview worked but the others did not.

Comment: We're having a bit of an issue with our api, and are working on the fix right now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dodge update to some API dependencies caused a bit of cascading failure.

It's been fixed now.