# My question related with yesterday's API problems has disappeared without a trace!

Tags: support, specific-question

I've asked a question here about the links for all my other user accounts on the network, that has disappeared from my profile.

**Relevant print-screen:**

[image]

Some comments had been placed, confirming the veracity of the reported issue. One of those comments also referred that "someone" had broken the API, and by following the provided link to another issue related with the broken API, an answer provided by a moderator, informed that the API issue could bring up unexpected results for a short period of time across the network.
Even a few minutes later the issue that I've reported was starting to appear resolved!

Today, I can't find any trace of the question and any related interaction with it!

**Did the question get deleted... or something else?**

- If it was, shouldn't [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), or some from of information have been passed to me?
- If not, where's the question?

Comment: You might want to send some love to [Show all of my question/answers to me even if they are deleted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted) and [Are MSO questions deleted too fast?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135606/are-mso-questions-deleted-too-fast)

Comment: (And, [JPEG](http://lbrandy.com/blog/2008/10/my-first-and-last-webcomic/)? `;-)`)

Comment: @Arjan, proper love was given, tks by the links, I'll keep an eye out for changes :)

Comment: @Arjan, using GIMP for that, and on this particular image, with .jpg, I got a file size 3 times smaller. But I tend to use .png, all comes down to the file size :)

Comment: Well, your 486x99 JPEG is `Content-Length: 5678` while [this 510x173 PNG](http://i.stack.imgur.com/OUHAd.png) is 3454... ;-) ([source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136368/other-stackexchange-accounts-are-not-shown-in-my-profile))

Comment: (As an aside: your question [is here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136285/looking-at-my-profile-and-no-accounts-listed) but you'll need 10k to [see it](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Ucwdn.png).)

Comment: @Arjan, yap, still working towards 10k ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question did get deleted right after being marked `status-completed`.  I'm guessing it was deleted because that bug was reported several times by different people and there's no use keeping duplicate bug reports around.  (This is one of the ways Meta is a little bit different from other sites in the SE network.  Sometimes duplicates are deleted.)

You probably should have been notified via comment, but it looks like someone forgot.  Here are the links to the related bug reports.

- [Oops! Something Bad Happened! Newsletter preview](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136283/1288)
- [Numbers wrong on StackExchange.com All Sites tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/136299/1288)

Comment: Tks for your prompt answer. Just thought that on these cases I would get a short notification, or, as you mentioned, someone forgot about it :)

Answer (score 5):

It actually was [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), then closed as a (spiritual) duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136299/numbers-wrong-on-stackexchange-com-all-sites-tab), then deleted.

The issue was very localised in time, so I assume the feeling was that keeping multiple questions around which all described the API being broken for a few minutes wasn't particularly useful.

Comment: Tks for the clarification! Just thought that on these cases I would get a short notification, as mentioned by @Bill the Lizard.

Comment: Accepted Bill's answer because it was more detailed, no hard feelings! ;)

Answer (score 3):

StackExchange staff regularly and massively deletes questions related to issues they consider fixed or irrelevant.

Comment: No, they don't, actually.

Comment: @jcolebrand, Jeff openly admits it an encourages this behaviour.

Comment: Jeff is no longer there.