# Other Stack Exchange accounts are not shown in my profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, linked-accounts

It seems that my profile no longer shows other accounts that I have in Stack Exchange:

> #### [0 Accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/1074647/pablo?tab=accounts)
>
> You have no other accounts on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/)

[image]

I haven't checked all my accounts, but it's happening at least in Stack Overflow, Meta and Board and Card Games. This morning, I could see my other accounts just fine. It's a bit of a bother because I use those links to change between my accounts.

Comment: The API is down at the moment, the information should reappear once it's back up.

Comment: Related, the earlier (resolved at the time) [Numbers wrong on StackExchange.com All Sites tab](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136299/numbers-wrong-on-stackexchange-com-all-sites-tab) (and the deleted [Looking at my profile and no accounts listed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136285/looking-at-my-profile-and-no-accounts-listed)).

Comment: I don't get it, every time this happens someone files a bug. It says "Profile information is temporarily unavailable" -- which part of that screams "unexpected bug"?

Comment: @Michael, I am to blame for that part about seeing that message. When I edited, there were no hits for "0 Accounts", so I added that. And I could not post an answer about clicking the header (not too obvious, I'd say) as this question was still closed at the time. I've moved that part into the answer now. Hope [this will stay around](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135606/are-mso-questions-deleted-too-fast) for future reference...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was a temporary bug.

Clicking the "0 Accounts" header would get one:

> Profile information is temporarily unavailable
>   Account information is temporarily unavailable

[image]

My profile appeared just like it, and now its fine.